# Select shape at a specific location

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I have some slides in powerpoint. I want to be able to select shape at a specific x,y location by going through each slide. Shapes are different in sizes, but always are selectable through clicking at the x,y location.

How can I select the shape in VBA?

Comment: What have you tried after doing your research and where did you run into trouble?

Comment: If you haven't ever programmed PPT an excellent starting point is https://www.rdpslides.com/pptfaq/

Answer (score 0):

Here's a typical loop through every shape on every slide, you'll use this a lot in PowerPoint VBA. This assumes there is only one shape on one slide that meets the criteria. This finds a shape within a range of positions, in case your measuring is slightly off:

```
Sub SelectShape()
    Dim oSlide As Slide
    Dim oShape As Shape
    
    For Each oSlide In ActivePresentation.Slides
        For Each oShape In oSlide.Shapes
            If oShape.Top > 10 And oShape.Top < 50 And oShape.Left > 10 And oShape.Left < 50 Then
                oShape.Select
            End If
        Next oShape
    Next oSlide
End Sub
```

Other sites for learning PowerPoint VBA:

[How to use VBA in PowerPoint: A beginner’s guide](https://www.brightcarbon.com/blog/how-to-use-vba-in-powerpoint/)

[Programming PowerPoint](http://www.pptfaq.com/#name_PROGRAMMING_POWERPOINT)

[Tips for using VBA in Powerpoint](http://www.pptalchemy.co.uk/powerpoint_hints_and_tips_tutorials.html#vba)

[PowerPoint VBA](http://skp.mvps.org/vba.htm#.XiHixchKhuc)

[Powerful PowerPoint for Educators](https://evergreen.loyola.edu/marco/www/PowerfulPowerPoint/)

Comment: Thanks. But the code you provided is testing the top-left corner is in certain area. 

What if the shape is expanded in next slide? The left-top corner may go out of that area. But our point location will be the same.

Comment: Please check this video to explain my problem:https://youtu.be/7AzFmX-yzTc
Here my center point is the location that can be clicked to select the shape in any slide. That I want to achieve in VBA.

Comment: That extra information is not in your original post. If you're trying to center objects, get the slide dimensions and object dimensions and do some math. Please post again if you need me to figure that out for you.

Comment: Thanks John. Selecting shape within an area does not help me. There are many others shapes in the presentation (not shown in video for simplicity). 

So I need code just that is like clicking at some x,y position.

Or is there a way to simulate a mouse click?

Comment: Simulating a mouse clicking is called "selecting" and uses the _Select_ method as illustrated in my code. Your question doesn't include your new requirements, but I have answered it as you wrote it. I would appreciate an upvote, thanks.